# Representing a special value in Python?

Tags: python, constants

I want to represent the value of `nil`, a value specific to my application, and distinguish it from the `None` built in to Python. What is the most elegant way to do this? Note that `nil` is a unique constant value.

Answer (score 6):

Use a sentinel object:

```
nil = object()
```

Now you can test for `is nil` or `is not nil` just as you can test for `None`.

Any code that uses this does, of course, have to import it from the module that defines it; it is not a built-in the way `None` is built-in.

Comment: If I make another constant in the same way, will that be distinct from `nil`? And is the best practice to simply leave nil in global scope in a file, if I want to expose it as much as a regular class (since I essentially want this to represent a class with only one object).

Comment: If you test with `is` the other value will be different.

Comment: @Matthias For `object` instances, even `==` will consider them distinct. It's just not idiomatic to compare such "singletons" with `==` (also applies to `None`, `Ellipsis` and `NotImplemented`).

Comment: @delnan: Still learning after all those years ...

Comment: @user3793111: yes, another constant will be entirely distinct.